# Unable to delete cookie from my browser even I have logged out

Tags: node.js, express

I was making backend for my todo app. In this backend i also integrated user authentication login/logout/register. So when I try to logout from frontend then the controller(logout) in which i have delecleared to put cookie:null is working proper since i am receiving the response as user is logged out successfully but my cookie is not deleteing

Here is my code for logout controller:-

```
export const logout = (req, res) => { 
    res.status(200).cookie('token',null,{
        httpOnly:true,
        expires:new Date(Date.now())
    }).json({
        sameSite:process.env.NODE_ENV === "Development" ?"lax":"none",
        secure:process.env.NODE_ENV ==="Development" ?false:true,
        success:true,
        message:`User logged out successfully`,
    })
   
}
```

I was trying to logout but cookie is not deleting

Comment: How are you making the request? Is it cross-origin?

Answer (score 0):

You are using ExpressJS, right? Then you can simple clear your cookie and redirect the client like this:

```
export const logout = (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie('yourCookieName');
  res.redirect('/login'); //Redirect the user to login screen
};
```

Comment: `export const logout = (req, res) => { 
    res.clearCookie('token');
    res.status(200).json({
        sameSite:process.env.NODE_ENV === "Development" ?"lax":"none",
        secure:process.env.NODE_ENV ==="Development" ?false:true,
        success:true,
        message:`User logged out successfully`,
    })
   
}`
So I made changes in my code of logout controller.But as soon as I refresh my react page the cookie is appearing again in browser

Comment: In React or frontend, you must clear the cookie as soon as the logout API call response is recieved. I don't think it will clear automatically.

Comment: so what should I do know?

Comment: You should manually clear the cookie as soon as you got 200 response for logout API call.